# Слитное и раздельное написание не

Tags: орфография

Здравствуйте!
Подскажите, пожалуйста, в предложении "На них, любуясь, смотрит уже не молодая женщина, но и она одета ярко" нужно ли писать не молодая слитно. При этом, в описываемой картине "Весенний солнечный день" женщина не старая, но и не молодая, то есть хотелось подчеркнуть то, что она именное не молодая, а не старая. До этого было написано о двух молодых девушках.
Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если Вы хотите подчеркнуть, что женщина - не молодая, а *чуть-чуть постарше молодой*, то пишите раздельно. Написание *немолодая* = *старая* с оттенком политкорректности.

Comment: А если отрицается именно то, что он молодая, как бы противопоставление тем девушкам, которые молодые...

Comment: На Ваш выбор, дружище! Я-то сам женщину не видел, оценить не могу, насколько она там немолодая) Автору же предоставлено право решать и оценивать...

Comment: Просто я ученик еще, отличник, но сейчас с русским плоховато, а тут еще и такая 4ка вышла=))

Comment: Уже не молодая ~~~ 40, уже немолодая ~~~ 50...  
Но могут быть и другие мнения)

Answer (score 3):

Раздельное написание можно обосновать только отрицанием.

Answer (score 1):

Попробую предложить следующее решение.

Для слов "молодой - старый" действует так называемая градация признака по его нарастанию, когда форма написания имеет конкретный смысл: молодой →  (уже)не молодой, но (еще) не старый → немолодой (почти старый) → старый.

Написание "уже не молодой", "еще не старый" близки устойчивым (традиционным) написаниям и обозначают средний возраст.

Answer (score 0):

Смотрит - какая женщина? Уже немолодая. Может, она и не старая, но не молодая - это точно. Последующее "но" не является проивопоставлением в прямом смысле слова. Оно подчёркивает, что женщина одета так, как одеваются молодые, хотя сама она к ним не относится... Предложение корявое, нечёткое по смыслу - даже если оно написано Ф. М. Достоевским, который писал душою, а не головою. Согласен с [@Татьяна](/users/108/%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B0) Гуса...

Answer (score -1):

Уже немолодая.
Пишем слитно, т.к. условий для раздельного написания нет.